# Verify collection instance method is called on in Rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Given the following:

inside class Groomer

```
def groom_dogs
  client.dogs.groom
end
```

and inside class Dog

```
def self.groom
  all.groomable.update_all(:groomed, 1)
end
```

How would you verify the dogs class receives the correct collection for groom?

```
expect(Dog).to receive(:groom)
```

will verify the correct method was called, but I would also like to do something like

```
expect(Dog).to receive(:groom).with(someowner.dogs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do this:

```
expect(client.dogs).to receive(:groom)
```